# How to typeset mathematical set with conditions in multiple rows

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

With the TeX code

```
\begin{equation}
  \max\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{n}|\langle x^{(i)},b\rangle|^2\;\mid\vbox{
  \hbox{Condition 1}
  \hbox{Condition 2}
  \hbox{Condition 3}
}\right\}
\end{equation}
```

I get the output

[image: output of code sample]

How can I achieve the following two things?

1. The separator produced by `\mid` shall have the same height as the curly brackets.
2. The three conditions shall be centered vertically.

Comment: [tag:braket] might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `tabular` instead of the `\vbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \max\left\{ \sum_{i=1}^{n}|\langle x^{(i)},b\rangle|^2\;
    \begin{tabular}{|l}
      Condition 1 \\
      Condition 2 \\
      Condition 3
\end{tabular}
\right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `\middle\vert` to draw a full-height vertical bar. Use an `array` environment to hold the conditions -- I assume the conditions will be mostly math-mode material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\text" macro
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \max
  \left\{ 
  \sum_{i=1}^{n}|\langle x^{(i)},b\rangle|^2
  \;\middle\vert\;
  \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
  \text{Condition 1}\\
  \text{Condition 2}\\
  \text{Condition 3}
  \end{array}
  \right\}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is also a perfect answer. Can `\middle` be also applied to different things than `\vert` to stretch them?

Comment: @phinz: `\middle` can be applied to any stretchable "fence" symbol, not just `\vert`. Give `\Vert` a try, say.